# Flex Layout Fluid and Fixed Width

Tags: css, less, flexbox

I have stumbled upon flex and I am trying to create a layout as such.

```
<div class="charts">
  <div class="chart longer">
  </div>
  <div class="chart short">
  </div>
</div>
```

I will have a `flex div` which will be fluid, and a `fixed width div` which will stay 200px.

I have used the following css and have succeeded.

```
.charts {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.chart.longer {
  flex: 1;
}
.chart.short {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}
```

From here, I want the longer div to stay fluid and be 100%, and `.chart.sort` to clear to a new line and take up 100% width at the following breakpoint.

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    // Help needed here
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below `768px`, you can assign `flex-direction: column` to the parent element. Child elements will stretch to `100% width`.

```css
.charts {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.chart.longer {
  flex: 1;
  background: tomato;
}
.chart.short {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background: lightblue;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .charts {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="charts">
  <div class="chart longer">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="chart short">
    B
  </div>
</div>
```